# Modals stop working when adding a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, paypal, modal-dialog

I'm working with the Paypal API and the "mercadopago" API, and in the same page, I have two modals, one is for buying a book using Paypal and the other using mercadopago.

The problem is when I add the variable:

```
$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```

All the modals stop working, and I really can't understand why.

Here's the code of my mercadopago-modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mercadopago" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="color:black">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <p><strong>Terminos y condiciones.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <form name="form"  method='post' action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:30px" oninput="precio.value = parseInt(numero.value)*10">
                <p>Antes de comprar, por favor, lea cuidadosamente los términos y condiciones de la compra en los siguientes dos enlaces:</p>
                <a href="objects/condiciones.docx" download>-Términos y Condiciones de compras para la adquisición del libro de parte de Becuadro Editores,</a><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="xD"> He leído y acepto los términos y condiciones y soy responsable por la compra.<br><br>
                <input type="number" id="numero" min="1" value="1" style="text-align:center"><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="precio" value="10" style="text-align:center" disabled>
                <script>
                $('#numero').bind('click keyup', function(){
                var hello = $(this).val();
                $("#check").val(hello);
                });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                            if($(this).attr("value")=="xD"){
                                $(".lol").toggle();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <?php
                require_once 'mercadopago.php';
                $cantidad = '<script> document.write(hello) </script>';
                $mp = $mp = new MP('keyone', 'keytwo');
                $preference_data = array(
                    "items" => array(
                        array(
                            "title" => "Las torres captivas",
                            "quantity" => $cantidad,
                            "currency_id" => "VEF",
                            "unit_price" => 700.00,
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                //$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="lol" style="display:none;">
                         <a href="<?php echo $preference['response']['init_point'];?>">Pagar</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Right now it works because the line that contains `$preference` as commented, but the "pay" button doesn't work because it needs the `$preference"` value.

How can I go about fixing it?

Comment: why do you have `document.write` in there for `quantity`? That's just asking for problems. Is there a php error causing part of the page not to print?

Comment: I use it to take the number of items @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl that's the problem, i remove the document.write and it works, but now i need to take the number value

Comment: take it where? Code shown doesn't seem to include what you do with that array